# Converting POST data from json-text to PHP objects?

Tags: php, json, email, post, smtp

I am trying to setup an automatic email handling. I am using external service https://www.email2json.net to convert emails to JSON/text format that is called on a webhook URL in my website.

How can I grab the raw post data and convert it to an object in PHP ?
Hence converting the email jebrish to something meaningful ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you nedd json_decode ?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt.  The very least would be to post the jebrish you are getting via the hook , and the php code you wrote to try and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a JSON object sent via POST, so you should first retrieve the input object with:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Then you can easily handle this JSON object by using the `json_decode` native function to convert it into an associative array:

```
$decoded_input = json_decode($input, true);
```

Hope this helped.